# <noscript> tag for a single element or something similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have an `Impressum` link that pops up the `Impressum` div.

```
<a data-open="something">Impressum</a>

<div class="reveal" id="something" data-reveal>
   <img src="images/reverseLogo.png">
   <h1>Impressum</h1>
   <p> ligula mattis placerat.</p>
   <p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien.</p>
   <p>Suspendisse eu ligula. </p>
   <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I would like to ask if there is any way (I know that exists but i do not know how can i achieve it) to redirect to another page if `Javascript` is disabled on the browser. I currently use:

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=impressum.html">
</noscript>
```

The problem is that if the `Javascript` is not enabled, It redirects the page given.
What i want is to redirect to the `impressum page` ONLY when i click on the `impressum link`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about going the other way around? so instead of <a data-open="something">Impressum</a> you create a <a href="./impressum.html">Impressum</a> and then your js changes this to your data-open construct. this way, if js is not activated, it would have the link and elsewhere, the js will change it...

Answer (score 1):

easiest way would be, to have both links in your dom. by default, the nojs imprint link is shown. the imprint popup link is hidden.
then on DOM ready, your js just toggles the visibility...

html

```
<a href="./impressum.html" class="nojsimprint">Impressum</a>
<a data-open="something" class="jsimprint">Impressum</a>
```

css

```
.jsimprint{
display: hidden;
}
```

js

```
$().ready(){
  $(".nojsimprint").hide();
  $(".jsimprint").show();
}
```